# Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Box Bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox 5.1.10. Bluetooth is working fine on Host Machine but on VB Ubuntu it is not working. In Ubuntu System Setting -> Hardware -> Bluetooth, it is not showing any adapter. Please advise how to fix this issue.
[image: Ubuntu Shows No Bluetooth Adaptor found]

[image: Devive Manager]

Answer (score 3):

After performing below steps, I got solved on my VM Ubuntu 16.04

1. Disable Bluetooth Adapter from Device Manager in Host Machine.
2. Disable all Services in Host Machine that are using Bluetooth. (TaskManager -> Services -> Press B to find Bluetooth Services & Stop)
3. Start VB Ubuntu
4. Enable Bluetooth Adapter from Device Manager in Host Machine.
5. In VB, goto Device -> USB -> Select Bluetooth Radio
6. Open Terminal to check bluetooth status: sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status

If you get Status as Active: active (running), then you have configured Bluetooth correctly.

Comment: This solution probably works for an external bluetooth that is connected via USB. How could I use the built-in native bluetooth device that came with my labtop? The settings in VM do not have anything related to bluetooth.